# { "code": -32000, "message": "invalid opcode: opcode 0xfe not defined" }

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-debugging

When distributing prize, this error will show:{ "code": -32000, "message": "invalid opcode: opcode 0xfe not defined" }

full code here:https://github.com/laronlineworld/bettingOrig/blob/main/BettingOrgi.sol

Anyone could help figuring out the distribution of prizes?

```
/* Function to close voting and handle payout. Can only be called by the owner. */
function closeVoting() onlyOwner public returns (bool) {
    require(bettingActive);
    bytes32 winningCandidate = candidateList[getWinner()];

    // getting list of winners and losers
    // and the money lost by all losers
    address[] memory winners;
    uint256 numWinners = 0;
    uint256 numLosers = 0;
    uint256 surplus = 0;
    for (uint x = 0; x < betters.length; x++) {
        if (bets[winningCandidate][betters[x]] > 0) {
            winners[numWinners++] = betters[x];
        } else {
            surplus += bets[winningCandidate][betters[x]];
            numLosers++;
        }
    }

    // keeping 10% as service fee and distribute rest among the winners
    uint256 prize = surplus * 9 / 10;
    // calculate prize per winner
    prize = prize / numLosers;
    // distribute the prize to the winners alongwith the money they bet in
    for (x = 0; x < winners.length; x++) {
        winners[x].transfer(prize + bets[winningCandidate][winners[x]]);
    }
    // Close the betting period
    bettingActive = false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The array `winners` is never initialized.

```
address[] memory winners;
```

So the first time it is used it generates an error.

```
winners[numWinners++] = betters[x];
```

Solidity doesn't admit dynamic arrays in memory.

The solution is to allocate the array before assigning elements.

```
address[] memory winners = new address[](betters.length);
```

And then use `numWinners` instead of `winners.length`.

Comment: whats the solution mate?

Comment: @LloydRamos The solution is to allocate the array before assigning elements.

Comment: You mean I'll change address[] memory winners; ---> address[] memory winners = new address[](betters.length); ? What do you mean of this ? "And then use numWinners instead of winners.length."?

Comment: @LloydRamos Yes, it is in the answer how to initialize the address array in memory. The code uses `winners.length` as the number of winners, but it is being allocated before adding elements so its length will always be equal to `betters.length`. To get the actual number of winners use `numWinners` instead.